# Building and debugging Cordova - Windows applications from WebStorm

Tags: cordova, webstorm

I did the settings needed for building Cordova applications, written in official WebStorm site.

In the run configurations, at the platform dropdown, there are some platforms but not Windows. Closest ones are windows8 and wp8. When I set to windows8, it gives:

> "Error: Platform "windows8" not recognized as a core Cordova platform. See `cordova platform list`"

and running 'cordova platform list' outputs "windows" platform not "windows8".

Any help about this will be appreciated.

Comment: *(for reference purposes)* Same question on WebStorm forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000107804-Building-and-debugging-Cordova-Windows-applications-from-Webstorm

Answer (score 0):

"windows" platform is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-21081](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21081) for updates

Comment: It's very disappointing. It looks the issue you sent has opened almost one year ago and there is still no update from it. Is there any other Jetbrains IDE  which has support also for Cordova -  Windows platform?